# React Router BrowserRouter History Push & Google Analytics

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-router-v4

I Have a Carousel Component and I wanted to change the URL so that google analytics could see to which steps the user went (without reloading the page).

I used React Router with its BrowserRouter component to update the route with the help of `` this.props.history.push(`#${value}`); `` and `withRouter` which successfully updates the URL route. But Google Analytics doesn't seem to see the difference... The website site is at this link If you wanna check the behavior: 
http://upscale-technology.com

Comment: GA won't fire any hit itself on history Push. If there is a history push, then you need to fire the pageview by placing a trigger on the same.

Comment: I was able to find this module with your help that I think will hopefully do the job : https://github.com/nfl/react-metrics ! Thanks alot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally your Google Analytics details are added to the HTML file triggering a page view when it is loaded. When you visit another page of the same website and Google Analytics is implemented there, it will log the new page.

In a single page application, routing is taken care of on the client without page reloads. What you are looking for is a way to let Google Analytics know that it should log a page view when a certain action is taken. It could be a click event, state change or a route change. It's up to you.

To achieve this you can use the [React-GA](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga) library. Use it in the following way.

```
// Import it at the top of the file
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

// Initialize it once, e.g. in your componentDidMount for example.
ReactGA.initialize('UA-000000-01');

// Whenever you want to log anything to Google Analytics, use the below. 
ReactGA.pageview('/carousel/#1');
```

**NOTE:**
Be careful where you implement the `.pageview([url])` function. If you are not careful it might be triggered on a re-render. This would mean you get false page views in you metrics skewing your analytics.

Comment: `// Whenever you want to log anything to Google Analytics, use the below` misses something important, IMO, the standard feature is when the router changes history.location — so this one has to be automatic, not call by hand.